# Load page specific children from XML & PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file where information is displayed based on the id defined in the url. For example, if the id=vladivostok `school-parser.php?id=vladivostok`, this information is displayed:

```
Vladivostok University
Vladivostok
Russia
Russian
```

coming from this xml file:

```
<schools>
    <school type="vladivostok">
        <name>Vladivostok University</name>
        <city>Vladivostok</city>
        <country>Russia</country>
        <language>Russian</language>
    </school>
    <school type="florianapolis">
        <name>Florianapolis University</name>
        <city>Florianapolis</city>
        <country>Brazil</country>
        <language>Portuguese</language>
    </school>
    <school type="gatineau">
        <name>Gatineau University</name>
        <city>Gatineau</city>
        <country>Canada</country>
        <language>French</language>
    </school>
</schools>
```

Currently, name, city, country and language are all displayed. I would like to display only one or two of the four but not necessarily all four. Here is my php code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file('schools.xml');

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {  
   $role = $child->attributes();
   foreach($child as $key => $value) {           
       if($role == $id) {
            echo $value . "<br />";
       }            
   }
}
```

Comment: To display a specific number of items you would have to switch to a for loop, count the children and set a limiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$string = '<schools>
    <school type="vladivostok">
        <name>Vladivostok University</name>
        <city>Vladivostok</city>
        <country>Russia</country>
        <language>Russian</language>
    </school>
    <school type="florianapolis">
        <name>Florianapolis University</name>
        <city>Florianapolis</city>
        <country>Brazil</country>
        <language>Portuguese</language>
    </school>
    <school type="gatineau">
        <name>Gatineau University</name>
        <city>Gatineau</city>
        <country>Canada</country>
        <language>French</language>
    </school>
</schools>';

//$id = $_GET['id'];
//$xml = simplexml_load_file('schools.xml');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);//test
$id = 'florianapolis';//test

foreach($xml->school as $key=>$data) { 
    if(strtolower($id) == strtolower($data['type'])){
        echo $key.' name:'.$data->name.' city:'.$data->city.' country:'.$data->country.' language:'.$data->language.'<br/>';
    }

}
```